# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Tags: c#, rest, api, .net-core

I am writing a REST API in .net core. I am trying to test the API using Postman and I am getting an error saying

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

I know this error occurs when the route does not match. Not sure, what am I doing wrong with the route. Below is my code with the Route at the top:

```
namespace RecLoad.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class RecLoadPrimeController : ControllerBase
    {
        [Route("RecLoadPrime/insertRecLoadData/{RecStartDate}/{RecEndDate}")]
        [HttpPost]
        public void insertRecLoadData(string RecStartDate, string RecEndDate)
        {
            RecLoadDataProvider dataProvider = new RecLoadDataProvider();
            dataProvider.InsertCardsData(RecStartDate, RecEndDate);
        }
    }
}
```

The URL that I am trying to test in Postman is below:

```
 https://localhost:44360/api/RecLoadPrime/insertRecLoadData/?RecStartDate=01/01/2020&RecEndDate=01/02/2020
```

I am very new to API, this is the first API that I am writing. Below is the image for application structure. Its extremely simple:

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that you specify that  RecStartDate and RecEndDate are part of the path but pass them like query parameters - decide which way you want to go. Obviously in your real code you are using ISO81- (https://xkcd.com/1179/) for date values, so that should be fine to put in path or query params.

Comment: so do I need to change anything or the code and URL looks fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 404 error means not found. This means Postman cant find the end point you are trying to hit.

1. Your `[Route]` attribute needs to be updated. The root of this endpoint (controller) it's `RecLoadPrime`. So get rid of that part. If you are just trying to test, update it to `[Route("insert")]`.

   - Using `?` in your URL means you are passing query parameters. Which are usually used on GET requests not on POST requests.
   - Web API expects you to use Model Binding for passing in parameters. Meaning map the post parameters to a strongly typed .NET object, not to single parameters. Alternatively, you can also accept a `FormDataCollection` parameter on your API method to get a name value collection of all POSTed values.
   - For example: Create a small class called `Card`, with the properties `startDate`, and `endDate`. Make them `DateTime`. Now use that in the method signature `public void insertRecLoadData([FromBody]Card card)`
2. In Postman, you are now going to use the Body option and create a JSON representation of this new class we created.

   - For example: `{ "startDate": "2020-03-23", "endDate": "2020-03-27" }`
   - In the route, you are going to use: `POST |  https://localhost:44360/api/insertRecLoadData/insert`

Make sure you set breakpoints in your controller. Not sure how you have setup your project but I'd suggest reading up more on how to setup a Web API using ASP.NET Core. Look into RESTful design to also get an idea on how to best setup these end points.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

The current route configuration on your controller and on your action will result in duplicated section in your route. Specifically, the route the action will be associated with will be "api/RecLoadPrime/RecLoadPrime/insertRecLoadData/{RecStartDate}/{RecEndDate}".

Consider removing the `RecLoadPrim/` prefix from your action route attribute as follows:

```cs
 [Route("insertRecLoadData/{RecStartDate}/{RecEndDate}")]
```

Comment: The URL that I will be putting in POSTman will be this : https://localhost:44360/api/RecLoadPrime/insertRecLoadData/?RecStartDate=01/01/2020&RecEndDate=01/02/2020  OR it will be like this: https://localhost:44360/api/insertRecLoadData/?RecStartDate=01/01/2020&RecEndDate=01/02/2020

Comment: Hi @Anjali. you have two options. If you don't touch your code, you can reach it with the following url: `localhost:44360/api/RecLoadPrime/RecLoadPrime/insertRecLoadData/{RecStartDate}/{RecEndDate}` (with filled in values).

If you want to fix it and do what I suggest, you will be able to call it with `localhost:44360/api/RecLoadPrime/insertRecLoadData/{RecStartDate}/{RecEndDate}`